# Swift Table View Cell changes gradient Color after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I just realized that my table view is not working correctly, after checking my App on multiple devices. I am currently working on a View that contains a Scroll View at the top, and an TableView at the bottom.

When I was creating the View I was working with an Iphone XS Max as my testing device, and everything worked fine. However, when the device gets smaller the Table View starts to do weird things.

Thats what I want the table view to look like:

[Table View on Iphone XS Max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJOT9.png)

On smaller devices the background color of the last table view cell is not green (what it should be according to code), instead it has the same color as the first cell.

When I scroll back to the top, the first cell has the color the last cell should have according to my code

Here is my cellForRowAt IndexPath

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GruppenCell", for: indexPath) as! GroupCell
    cell.bgView.backgroundColor = nil
    cell.bgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    cell.bgView.clipsToBounds = true
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.white
            , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Spatzen().color, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
        cell.groupLabel!.text = "Spatzen"
        cell.iconImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "SpatzIcon")
    }

    else if(indexPath.row ==  1) {
        cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.white
            , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Elefanten().color, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
        cell.groupLabel!.text = "Elefanten"
        cell.iconImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "elefantIcon")
    }

    else if(indexPath.row == 2) { 
        cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.white
            , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Mäuse().color, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
        cell.groupLabel!.text = "Mäuse"
        cell.iconImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "mouseIcon")
    }

    else if(indexPath.row == 3) {
        cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.lightGray
            , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Pferde().color, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
        cell.groupLabel!.text = "Pferde"
        cell.iconImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "horseIcon")
        print("Ich bin der Pferd Index")
    }

    else if(indexPath.row == 4) {
        cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.lightGray
            , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Frösche().color, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
        cell.groupLabel!.text = "Frösche"
        cell.iconImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "FrogIcon")
    }
    else {
        cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.lightGray
            , colorTwo: UIColor.white, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Here is my Struct for the colors

```
struct KitaGruppen {

struct Spatzen{
    var name = "Spatzen"
    var name_lower = "spatzen"
    var color = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.871347487, blue: 0, alpha: 1)    
}

struct Elefanten{
    var name = "Elefanten"
    var name_lower = "Elefanten"
    var color = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.3798098862, blue: 1, alpha: 1)

}

struct Pferde{  
    var name = "Pferde"
    var name_lower = "pferde"
    var color = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
}

struct Frösche{
    var name = "Frösche"
    var name_lower = "frösche"
    var color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5412063003, green: 0.9987080693, blue: 0.2685243189, alpha: 1)
}

struct Mäuse{
    var name = "Mäuse"
    var name_lower = "Mäuse"
    let color = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9411764741, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.3529411852, alpha: 1)
}
}
```

Here is my Cell Class

```
class GroupCell: UITableViewCell {

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    self.iconImageView.image = nil
    self.groupLabel.text = ""

    self.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.white
        , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Spatzen().color, bounds_object: self.bgView)
}
```

I added the prepareForReuse Method to fix this error, but it did not have any affects.

I dont know if it is important, but here is my setGradientBackground Method:

```
    func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, bounds_object: UIView){

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds_object.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

The weird thing is that the only cell data that has this bug is the gradient color. The text for the text label, and also the icons don't get mixed up at all.

Does anybody know any fix for this ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Consider that every call of `setGradientBackground` inserts a new `gradientLayer`.

Comment: Is there a quick workaround for that ? Its my first time working with gradient colors in  Swift so I dont really know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be caused by the fact that a new gradient layer is inserted every time `setGradientBackground` is called.

To avoid that check if the layer exists. If it exists update the colors otherwise create the new layer.

```
func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor, bounds_object: UIView){

    if let gradientLayer = layer.sublayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer {
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    } else {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds_object.bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

Actually `prepareForReuse()` is redundant because you can set image and text in the last `else` scope. It makes sure that all UI elements are set to a defined state.

Add these two lines and delete the entire `prepareForReuse()` method in `GroupCell`.

```
else {
    cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.lightGray
        , colorTwo: UIColor.white, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
    cell.iconImageView.image = nil
    cell.groupLabel.text = ""
}
```

A better syntax than `if - else if` in this case is a `switch`

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0: 
    cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.white
        , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Spatzen().color, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
    cell.groupLabel!.text = "Spatzen"
    cell.iconImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "SpatzIcon")

case 1:

    cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.white
        , colorTwo: KitaGruppen.Elefanten().color, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
    cell.groupLabel!.text = "Elefanten"
    cell.iconImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "elefantIcon")

...

default: 
    cell.bgView.setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor.lightGray
        , colorTwo: UIColor.white, bounds_object: cell.bgView)
    cell.iconImageView.image = nil
    cell.groupLabel.text = ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! If you scroll very fast the first cell still has a green color for a split second, but I am more then happy with the result!!!

Comment: You can even remove the `bounds_object: UIView` parameter as the view is always the enclosing view. Then write `gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds` and remove the parameter also in all calls of the method. Und auf Englisch heisst Spatz *sparrow* 